# GitHub と ssh 接続を行うことのメリットは？

Tags: github, ssh

GitHub, ssh どちらも初心者ですが疑問に思ったことがありましたので質問させていただきます。

自分の認識としてはsshで公開鍵と秘密鍵を取得し設定することによって遠隔操作などの通信を暗号化することができるだと考えています。GitHubではsshを接続するような設定がありますが、そもそもGitHubでのリポジトリの設定が公開になっている時点で自分のpcとGitHubとの通信を暗号化する必要はないのではないかと考えました。

どなたかGitHubとssh接続することのメリット、またそもそもssh接続の自分の認識が間違っていたら教えていただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SSHで通信することの恩恵は、暗号化だけでなく**認証**の側面もあります。

例えば、GitHubにSSH接続する際には、登録されている公開鍵を用いて、接続主が誰であるかということがチェックされます。これにより、自分に成りすました誰か別の人がGitHubに接続して勝手に自分のリポジトリを操作するようなことを防ぐことができるのです。